# IBM Rhapsody: How can I use the value of another block?

Tags: rhapsody

In my Block A state machine, I'm trying to use the value of Block B's value property, but for some reason it won't let me. Is there a way to use another block's value property in a state machine?

Answer (score 2):

It should be easy if block `A` has a reference to Block `B` and the values are not private. Then in the state machine code it would be somthing like `itsB.getSomeValue();` The exact syntax will change depending on which language you are using.

Here is a test sample I made:

[image]

So if the client wanted to access something on the clock it would just use its `itsClock` reference. Here is an example of the client accessing it from its state machine:

[image]